# Optimizing double loop in 4d numpy tensor slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say that we have two numpy ndarrays with shapes:

`video.shape = (v, h, w, 3)`
and
`image.shape = (h, w, 3)`

We also have an array with shape `img.shape = (h,w)` that is integer and tells me which "frame" v to pick for each position h,w. To do this, one can use the loop:

```
for j in range(w):
    for i in range(h):
        image[i, j, :] = video[img[i, j], i, j, :]
```

However, this is **very** slow. Is it possible to do it without loops? Maybe reshaping the 2D coordinates into one and then reshaping it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one straightforward way

```
import numpy as np

v, h, w = 40, 50, 60

video = np.random.random((v,h,w,3))
img = np.random.randint(0, v, (h, w))

i, j = img.shape
i, j = np.ogrid[:i, :j]

image = video[img, i, j, :]

# check

for j in range(w):
    for i in range(h):
        assert np.all(image[i, j, :] == video[img[i, j], i, j, :])
```